# How do I make a matrix of matrices in python? (ValueError)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

So I want to make a 2x2 H matrix which has two matrices in it, like this:

[I can't add images yet, so please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wrDP.png)

The matrix in H should be a dim x dim matrix with v values in the main diagonal and w values in the diagonal below the main diagonal.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raEC1.png)

Here is the program for this:

```
def make_ham(v,w,dim):

    V = (scipy.sparse.eye(dim,k=0)*v).todense()   
    W = (scipy.sparse.eye(dim,k=-1)*w).todense() 

    Γ = V+W

    line = np.array([0,0,1,1])
    column = np.array([0,1,0,1])
    data = np.array([0,1,1,0]) 

    Hb = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((data,(line,column)), shape=(2,2), dtype=(np.float64)) 


    H = kron(Hb, Γ)*[[1],[0]]+kron(Hb, Γ.T)*[[0],[1]]

    return H
```

When I give a dim that's not 2, I get this error:

```
ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (2,1) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

I'm really stuck here, so thanks in advance for any kind of advice!:)

Comment: What `kron` are you using?  Careful with naive mixing of sparse and dense arrays.

Comment: That kind of error message is produced by matrix multiplication.  Whether that's the numpy `dot` or the sparse I can't say, since you did not provide the full traceback.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you could do using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

#Size of the inside matrices
N = 2

#Setting values of v and w for instance
v = 1
w = 2

#Making H a diagonal matrix
H = np.eye(N)
np.where(H==1, v, H) #Replacing 0 values by v
np.where(H==0, w, H) #Replacing 0 values by w

#Filling the upper triangle with random values (For instance)
T = np.random.random((N, N))
T *= 1-np.tri(*T.shape)

#Redefining H with the upper triangle
H = H + T

#Creating a null matrix of the shape as H
Z = np.zeros_like(H)

#Creating matrix of matrix
matrix_of_matrix = np.array([[Z,H],[H.T,Z]])

print(matrix_of_matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `sparse`.  `np.eye` has a `k` offset paramter.  And making the (2,2) `Hb` is a trivial task:

```
In [89]: v,w=2,3                                                                        
In [90]: Γ = np.eye(10,k=0)*v+np.eye(10,k=-1)*w                                                
In [91]: Γ                                                                                     
Out[91]: 
array([[2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [3., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 3., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 3., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 2.]])
In [92]: Hb = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])                                                          
In [93]: Hb                                                                                    
Out[93]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
In [94]: np.kron(Hb, Γ)                                                                        
Out[94]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 2., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0.],
       ....
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0.]])
In [95]: _.shape                                                                               
Out[95]: (20, 20)
```

`sparse.kron(Hb, Γ)` with your sparse `Hb` should give the same thing, but as a sparse matrix.

I suspect from the error message that `kron(Hb, Γ)*[[1],[0]]` is attempting a matrix product.  While the 2nd argument is clearly (2,1), I don't see why the first, the `kron()` is (3,3).  In any case there's clearly a mismatch in shapes, whether doing matrix product, element-wise product, sparse or dense.